# Primefaces dataTable redirect to a new tab on row select event

Tags: jsf, primefaces

So, i have a datatable :

```
<p:dataTable id="distributionGroupsTable" selectionMode="single"  scrollable="true" scrollHeight="600" 
        selection="#{manageDatasetGroupBean.selectedDatasetGroup}" rowKey="#{dg.datasetGroupId}" 
        value="#{manageDatasetGroupBean.datasetGroups}" var="dg"  sortBy="#{dg.datasetGroupId}"
        sortOrder="descending">

        <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{manageDatasetGroupBean.redirectListener}"
            update="distributionGroupsTable" />
```

the redirect listener is:

```
public void redirectListener() {
    ConfigurableNavigationHandler nh = (ConfigurableNavigationHandler) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().getNavigationHandler();
    nh.performNavigation("modify_dataset_group?faces-redirect=true&id=" + selectedDatasetGroup.getDatasetGroupId());
    selectedDatasetGroup = null;
}
```

and the form is set to: < h:form target="_blank" />.

If i place a command button with ajax false, it will redirect to a new tab. But, clicking on a row in the table redirects in the same tab, and I want it to redirect in a new one.
Any ideas how to implement that?

Comment: Try to get it to work with a commandButton with ajax=true and you have your solution for the rowselect to: see also https://www.google.nl/search?q=jsf+commandbutton+ajax+redirect+to+new+browser+tab

Comment: You're probably being harassed by your browser's popup blocker. Check your js console or your browser's address bar to confirm. You may have to carry out the navigation on the client side